# Invoking functions from nested modules in a script module do not always trigger a module to autoload

Tags: powershell

If I create a manifest module with nested modules, exported functions from all nested modules after the first do not appear in the list of available commands and don't trigger the module to autoload.

They also do not appear when I run "Get-Module -ListAvailable".

Only the exported functions from the first nested module appear in the list of commands.

If I explicitly import the module, all exported functions are available.

In the example below, Update-LegacyServices is not available until the module has been explicitly imported.

The only way I can make it work it to rename my module files to end with ps1 instead of psm1 and include them in ScriptsToProcess, which seems like a bad idea.

**Module manifest (psd1)**

```
@{

# Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest.
# RootModule = ''

# Version number of this module.
ModuleVersion = '1.0.0.1'

# ID used to uniquely identify this module
GUID = 'c11d6aca-d531-4d06-a732-5fb95113357f'

# Author of this module
Author = 'luke'

# Company or vendor of this module
CompanyName = ''

# Copyright statement for this module
Copyright = ''

# Description of the functionality provided by this module
# Description = 'MyBudget Developer Powershell Module'

# Minimum version of the Windows PowerShell engine required by this module
PowerShellVersion = '4.0'

# Name of the Windows PowerShell host required by this module
# PowerShellHostName = ''

# Minimum version of the Windows PowerShell host required by this module
# PowerShellHostVersion = ''

# Minimum version of the .NET Framework required by this module
DotNetFrameworkVersion = '4.5.0'

# Minimum version of the common language runtime (CLR) required by this module
CLRVersion = '4.0.30319.18444'

# Processor architecture (None, X86, Amd64) required by this module
# ProcessorArchitecture = ''

# Modules that must be imported into the global environment prior to importing this module
RequiredModules = 'BitsTransfer'

# Assemblies that must be loaded prior to importing this module
# RequiredAssemblies = @()

# Script files (.ps1) that are run in the caller's environment prior to importing this module.
ScriptsToProcess = @()

# Type files (.ps1xml) to be loaded when importing this module
# TypesToProcess = @()

# Format files (.ps1xml) to be loaded when importing this module
# FormatsToProcess = @()

# Modules to import as nested modules of the module specified in RootModule/ModuleToProcess
NestedModules =  @('database\Database.psm1', 'build\Build.psm1')

# Functions to export from this module
#FunctionsToExport = '*'

# Cmdlets to export from this module
CmdletsToExport = '*'

# Variables to export from this module
VariablesToExport = '*'

# Aliases to export from this module
AliasesToExport = '*'

# List of all modules packaged with this module.
ModuleList = @('database\Database.psm1', 'build\Build.psm1')

# List of all files packaged with this module
# FileList = @()

# Private data to pass to the module specified in RootModule/ModuleToProcess
# PrivateData = ''

# HelpInfo URI of this module
# HelpInfoURI = ''

# Default prefix for commands exported from this module. Override the default prefix using Import-Module -Prefix.
# DefaultCommandPrefix = ''

}
```

**Module 1 (Build\Build.psm1)**

```
function Update-LegacyServices()
{
    echo "Update"
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Update-LegacyServices
```

**Module 2 (database\Database.psm1)**

```
Function Get-Backup($directory, $name)
{
    echo "Get-Backup"
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Get-Backup
```

Comment: I think you have to uncomment `#FunctionsToExport = '*'` from the module manifest.

Comment: You think or you tested? Neither worked for me

Comment: As I said, I think. Just a hunch. If it doesn't work, so be it.

Comment: @LukeN I'm also having this problem (WMF 4.0), but I specify multiple PS1 files (each containing one individual function) rather than multiple PSM1 files. This is a team preference and does seem to be supported according to official MS documentation (-NestedModules can be an array, and contain PSM1, dll and PS1 files). Like you `Get-Module -ListAvailable`, under "ExportedCommands" only shows the first function/command in the first PS1 file specified in NestedModules.

Comment: This is the same when I run Test-ModuleManifest also. If I wrap multiple functions/commands into a single PS1 or PSM1, ExportedCommands shows all of them in this file, but it would not show the commands in the second or subsequent file in the NestedModules array. Of course again like you, if I explicitly import everything is fine. `FunctionsToExport = '*'` is my default setting. If I run `Get-Command -Module MyModule` it will show _all the functions (i.e. all the PS1 files)_.

Comment: What happens if you do this? Will this show commands from Database.psm1 and Build.psm1? Of course this doesn't solve the problem, but it'd be interesting to see if your experience is the same as mine. It's worth noting however that the entire autoloading experience seems inconsistent. Sometimes my scripts can successfully see a function from the second ps1 file and sometimes they cannot.

Comment: Further to this, I find that if I call a function from the first file referenced in NestedModules, the function in the second file in NestedModules can then be autoloaded. The inconstancy I'm seeing, is I suspect something to do with the CommandAnalysis folder located at "C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell". I think this folder is used to cache modules commands, and I suspect there is a TTL on them. I will test this and report back.

Comment: I tried "Get-Module -ListAvailable -Refresh" as well, but it didn't seem to update the cache.

Comment: What happens when you run `Get-Command -Module MyModule` @LukeN? Does it show commands from both modules? I have confirmed the following: If I import the module explicitly commands from both "modules" (or PS1 scripts) are available. This persists across PowerShell sessions (i.e. I can close PS, reopen and it's available). This is due to caching in the CommandAnalysis folder. It *does* have a TTL, because commands in the second module that were available across sessions last night, are no longer available this morning.

Comment: If I don't explicitly load the module, and call a function from the first module, functions from the second module become available but they don't persist across sessions.

Comment: I ended up blogging about this for clarity: [http://theboywonder.co.uk/2014/10/09/the-curious-case-of-powershell-module-autoloading-with-multiple-nested-modules/](http://theboywonder.co.uk/2014/10/09/the-curious-case-of-powershell-module-autoloading-with-multiple-nested-modules/)

Answer (score 3):

I had this line in my .psd1 file

```
FunctionsToExport = 'FuncFromMainPsm1 FuncFromSecondPsm1'
```

which was what I inferred from the line generated by Powershell Tools for Visual Studio:

```
# Functions to export from this module
FunctionsToExport = '*'
```

This caused my `Get-Module -ListAvailable` to show what looked like the right thing

```
Script     1.0        MyMModule                  FuncFromMainPsm1 FuncFromSecondPsm1
```

But when I called `FuncFromSecondPsm1` I'd get "The term 'FuncFromSecondPsm1' is not recognized...".

So I changed my export line to

```
FunctionsToExport = @('FuncFromMainPsm1', 'FuncFromSecondPsm1')
```

And now it all works. I can call both functions after my module loads, whether via autoload or `Import-Module`.

I have tried this with and without both `ModuleList` and `FileList` set. They make no difference.

Comment: This is working fine for my module with ModuleType = Script. I have another module with ModuleType = Manifest and it's not working! More investigations to follow

Comment: Confirmed: you seem to need to use a script manifest in this case. Set one of your scripts to be the root module, then the others can be nested modules. There is no noticeable difference between the one marked as the root module and all the others.

Answer (score 2):

Hy Paul, Hy Luken,

After struggling for a few hours on this topic (with the implicit and declared manifest approach), I opted for the auto generated manifest.
In essence, I wrote a ps1 script that generates the manifest, in two steps:

1. with some 'business' logic, discover what you want to expose
2. generate the module manifest

IMHO, Advantage of that approach: I 'fully' understand and master the exposure of the module content.

below you can find a PS code snippet that follows this approach, hoping it will benefit to other people.

```
# module discovery
$rootModule = "WdCore";
$modules = Get-ChildItem *.psm1;
$nestedmodulesNames = $modules | where { $_.BaseName -ne "WdCore"} | % { $_.BaseName } ;

# functions discovery
$modulesLines = $modules | Get-Content;
$functionsLines = $modulesLines | where { $_.contains("Function") };

$functionNamePattern = '^Function\s+(?<name>([a-z][0-9|A-Z|-]+))\s?{.*$';
$functionNames = $functionsLines | where { $_ -match $functionNamePattern } | select { $Matches['name'] } | % { $_.' $Matches[''name''] '};

# generate manifest
New-ModuleManifest `
    -Path ./WdTools.psd1 -RootModule $rootModule `
    -ModuleVersion '1.0' `
    -NestedModules $nestedmodulesNames `
    -FunctionsToExport $functionNames `
    -Guid '57D7F213-2316-4786-8D8A-3E4B9262B1E5' `
    -Author 'Blaise Braye' `
    -Description 'This module provides working directory tooling' `
    -PowerShellVersion '3.0' -ClrVersion '4.0';
```