# Why isn't my PowerShell module exporting members correctly and why isn't it exporting Nested Modules?

Tags: powershell, deployment, module, scripting

I'm working on a Quick Module CLI builder. The idea is you have my Module, which has commands like Add-QuickFunction, Add-QuickAlias, New-QuickModule, Remove-QuickCommand, etc.

As you build out the functions, your Modules continue to get built out. The plan is to create an Export-QuickModule and Export-QuickModule command, so that when you're ready to Export your module it's ready to be published, to your organization, or to a public gallery.

So the problem is two-fold.

1. The exported members do not match the commands in the module

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Module -Name QuickModuleCLI

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     0.1.3      QuickModuleCLI                      {New-QuickModule, Update-QuickModule}
```

Notice how it only includes 2 Exported commands. This is after I manually added Export-ModuleMember to my local system. Without having Export-ModuleMember, only New-QuickModule appears as exported.

But compare it to the actual list of Commands:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Command -Module QuickModuleCLI

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Add-QuickAlias                                     0.1.3      QuickModuleCLI
Function        Add-QuickFunction                                  0.1.3      QuickModuleCLI
Function        ConvertTo-PowershellEncodedString                  0.1.3      QuickModuleCLI
Function        Edit-QuickCommand                                  0.1.3      QuickModuleCLI
Function        New-QuickModule                                    0.1.3      QuickModuleCLI
Function        Remove-QuickCommand                                0.1.3      QuickModuleCLI
Function        Rename-QuickCommand                                0.1.3      QuickModuleCLI
Function        Reset-QuickCommand                                 0.1.3      QuickModuleCLI
Function        Set-Env                                            0.1.3      QuickModuleCLI
Function        Update-QuickModule                                 0.1.3      QuickModuleCLI
```

2. The Nested Module isn't getting imported into the PowerShell session until after I've imported the Module. I can deal with it by adding Import-Module to my $Profile if I have to, but I just want to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong.

What this means is, after opening a new session, I see the following:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Write-Test
Write-Test : The term 'Write-Test' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Write-Test
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Write-Test:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Import-Module QuickModuleCLI
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Write-Test
Hello
```

I use a dynamic self-rolled PowerShell generator to update the psd1 file and add to the FunctionsToExport. You can verify that when I Import-Module, it calls the NestedModules and imports it properly. However, on the computer I use to develop this Module in, I don't need to Import-Module in order for Write-Test to appear in my PowerShell Options. Is this an environmental thing that I have to just "deal with" or is this something you that can be fixed?

The code can be found here: https://github.com/EdLichtman/QuickModuleCLI
And you can try it out yourself with Import-Module QuickModuleCLI

Comment: I'm unable reproduce this locally, but tbh, I'm not sure what I'm trying to reproduce... I tried ```Import-Module QuickModuleCLI``` with a copy of your repo (which gave no errors), but ```Get-Module -Name QuickModuleCLI``` and ```Get-Command -Module QuickModuleCLI``` show zero exported commands, and ```NestedModules``` is an empty array in your *.psd1. Am I doing it right?

Comment: So this is a Quick Module Builder. It should have no NestedModules until you Create one, and if you try to add a quick function to a module that doesn't exist yet, then it will ask to create one for you.

It'll then create a module rooted under ${ModuleRoot}\Modules\$QuickModule. Once that module is created, it'll alter the ${ModuleRoot}\QuickModuleCLI file to add the new $QuickModule under the NestedModules

Comment: Let's say you have a certain path that you go to all the time. In my case, it's the (Split-Path $Profile). So I want to create a new Module called "GeneralUtility". In it, I'd want a new function Open-PSProfile. Open-PSProfile runs 'explorer (split-path $Profile)'. So I could run Add-QuickFunction GeneralUtility Open-PSProfile 'explorer (split-path $profile)' and then the nested module would get created and the function would get created in the nested module. When I open up another powershell session, I want Open-PSProfile to be exported without having to import-module. This is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 1 - ExportedCommands**

Here's a minimal repro for your issue with the `ExportedCommands` list not matching the result from `Get-Command`. I distilled it down to this by progressively removing chunks of code from your repo at https://github.com/EdLichtman/QuickModuleCLI until there was nothing left to remove:

**MyModule.psd1**

```bsh
@{

RootModule = "MyModule.psm1"

ModuleVersion = "0.1.4"

FunctionsToExport = @(
    "Add-MyAlias",
    "New-MyModule"
)

}
```

**MyModule.psm1**

```bsh
function global:Add-MyAlias {
    write-host "global:Add-MyAlias"
}

function New-MyModule {
    write-host "New-MyModule"
}
```

**Interactive**

```bsh
PS> Import-Module .\MyModule\MyModule.psd1 -Force

PS> Get-Module MyModule

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     0.1.4      MyModule                            New-MyModule

PS> Get-Command -Module MyModule

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Add-MyAlias                                        0.1.4      MyModule
Function        New-MyModule                                       0.1.4      MyModule
```

I don't know what the exact implication is when you use `global:` on an exported function (I'm assuming the function gets imported into the `global` scope rather than the module scope), but if you remove `global:` the function will suddenly appear in the `ExportedCommands` list again:

**Part 2 - Importing Modules**

PowerShell has a feature that will cause it to search for unknown commands in a set of predefined folder locations. This is called "Module Auto-Loading" and you can enable or disable the feature using the `$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference` variable as per [About Preference Variables](http://$PSModuleAutoloadingPreference) (hint: it's enabled by default).

The locations it searches are defined in an environment variable `PSModulePath` - see [About PSModulePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psmodulepath?view=powershell-7).

If you want the commands in your module to be discoverable and auto-loaded on first invocation, either install your module in one of the paths already added to the `PSModulePath` environment variable, or add your module's location to the path.

Comment: So your answer to part 1, OMG that makes so much sense! The commands are there but are obviously not part of the module scope and are therefore not exported! Now I'm trying to piece Part 2 together... for cleanliness in response I'll submit my question in another comment.

Comment: So, for part 2, that's amazing, thank you for this explanation. I could observe this behavior but I didn't know what it was called or how to look for information on it, so now that it has a name I can read up on it. However, NestedModules seems to work yet when I set my loading preference to all, it still isn't added in. Could this just be a limitation of how NestedModules is _supposed_ to be used, and I'm technically using it incorrectly? I suppose a workaround would to be adding a prompt (to make sure user is ok with it) to Add the new module root to the end of the PSModulePath...

Comment: but if I could get it to work via the psd1 configuration I'd much prefer that option.

Comment: If you can produce a minimal example of your remaining problem with Part 2 it's probably worth opening a new question - it's hard to give a meaningful answer without a concrete example to refer to.

Comment: I can do that for sure, but I thought my part 2 was a minimal example already? I'll be back in a few hours and will try to get the key points of it in a more "focused question" though. That way I can give it a bit more detail without obfuscating the problem with the sheer size of the wall of text. I'll come back here and link it, so I hope to see you on the new question. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: It'd preferably be easy to reproduce as well - ideally list the complete code for the files needed to reproduce the issue, and remove any code that doesn't directly contribute to the problem at hand. Make it as easy as just cut & pasting snippets and you're more likely to get an answer from someone - I had to do a bit of guesswork from your Part 1 description but luckily I was able to reproduce it before I gave up. If it had taken me another 5 minutes I might not have responded...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for some more detailed pointers...

Comment: Here's a concrete reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64216605/in-powershell-why-arent-the-functions-exported-in-my-nestedmodules-discoverabl. I'm pretty sure the answer is "it just don't work that way" but I'm hoping that you might have some good news that might be "well instead you can do..."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222565/discussion-between-mclayton-and-user3654055).

Comment: I've posted an answer to part 2 below. Thanks so much for your help in all this and sticking with it to get a working example of part 1

Answer (score 0):

So to follow up on part 2, it turns out the reason why is related to, in fact it's exactly the same behavior described in this answer:

[Invoking functions from nested modules in a script module do not always trigger a module to autoload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250806/invoking-functions-from-nested-modules-in-a-script-module-do-not-always-trigger)

My workaround was to add to the FunctionsToExport list, the functions within the NestedModules. Initially I did not think I could export functions that were not directly part of the parent module.